# Stop for loop when the if statement is true

Tags: python, python-3.x

Use while and if statements to count how many 0’s are before the first 1 (from left to right).

```
code = '00000000101100110001111110110011'

num_zero_before_1 = 0

for i in code:
  if i != '1':
    num_zero_before_1+=1

print(num_zero_before_1)
```

I cannot seem to get the answer

Comment: add `else: break`

Comment: or just: `code.index('1')`. see [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index).

Comment: Isn't your problem statement saying to use a `while` loop?

Comment: Or `len(code) - len(code.lstrip('0'))` (not as nice as `code.index('1')` (but this wouldn't fail with `code = '000000000’)`))

Comment: The way the problem is written it seems to be expecting `while code[num_zero_before_1] != '1': num_zero_before_1+=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a small mistake. You are counting zeroes by if condition using `i != '1'` but you should add else also to break the loop whenever the first `'1'` encountered, otherwise your loop will go on counting all zeroes.
Here is correct solution:

```
code = '00000000101100110001111110110011'

num_zero_before_1 = 0

for i in code:
    if i != '1':
        num_zero_before_1+=1
    else:
        break

print(num_zero_before_1)
```

Answer (score 3):

loops in python have two control statements: `continue` and `break`. Continue skips the rest of the iteration and starts from the top and break completely leaves the loop. So what you want here is to `break` on the `else` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you use `while` loop instead of `for... in` loop?
This solution should fulfill exercise assumptions:

```py
iterator = 0
while True:
    if code[iterator] != '1':
        iterator += 1
    else:
        break  # it stops the loop, goes out of it 
print(iterator)  # number of zero before '1'
```

---

However, this solution is shorter and easier, maybe it'll be useful to you:

```py
iterator = 0
while code[iterator] != '1':
    iterator += 1
print(iterator)  # number of zero before '1'
```